# if Condition to check if XPath Attribute Exists

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an xml file that is constructed like this

```
<listing ItemID="12345679" SKU="ABC123" Price="99.99" />
```

I have a `for loop` inside a `foreach loop`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $itemidcount; $i++) {
    $xpath = $xml->xpath('/sitename/listing[@ItemID=' . '"' . $itemid[$i] .'"' . ']');
    $prices[] = (string)$xpath[0]->attributes()->Price;
}
```

My issue is, if the `ItemID` `attribute` does not exist in the `for loop`, it outputs an error and stops my script.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/sitename/public_html/feeds/script.php on line 137

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attributes() on null in /home/sitename/public_html/feeds/script.php:137 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/sitename/public_html/feeds/script.php on line 137
```

I've tried doing a `count`

```
$count = count((string)$xpath[0]->attributes()->Price);
```

and wrapping it in `$prices[]`

```
if ($count > 0) {
    $prices[] = (string)$xpath[0]->attributes()->Price;
}
```

But the same error occurs.

How can I create an `if` that will skip over the `$prices[]` line if the `ItemID` `Attribute` is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the number of elements returned from the XPath call.  So

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath('/sitename/listing[@ItemID=' . '"' . $itemid[$i] .'"' . ']');
if (count($xpath) > 0) {
   $prices[] = (string)$xpath[0]->attributes()->Price;
}
```

Comment: What if the attribute 'Price' is not exists? I have the similar issue. Filter by data attribute value of 'a' elements but when I going to get the 'href' value: it returns ERROR: The current node list is empty. in ```Crawler->attr()```

Comment: @Sadee, you would have to check at each stage if there is anything to use.  So check the API for your library to see how to check that it exists and if there are any attributes.